# Python: read an Excel file using Pandas when the file has special characters in column headers

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xls, xlsx

I know you can read in Excel files with pandas, but I have had trouble reading in files where the column headings in the worksheets are not in a format easily readable like plain text.

In other words, if the column headings had special characters then the file would fail to import. Where as if you import data like that into Microsoft Access or other databases, you get the option to import anyway, or remove special characters.

My only solution to this has been to write an Excel macro to strip out characters not usually liked by databases when importing - and then import the file using python.

But there must be a way of handling this situation purely using python (which is a lot faster).

My question, how does python handle importing .xls and .xlsx files when the column headings have special characters which won't import?

Comment: please can you give an example? e.g. with an example spreadsheet and example code, I'm suprised that this doesn't "Just Work"TM. This *kinda* feels like a bug report, so maybe best posted as a github issue!

Comment: Thanks Andy Hayden I'll try and come up with an example and post it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "u" before your string. For example, if you're looking for a column named 'lissé' in a dataframe "df" then you should put df[u'lissé']